# Can't figure out regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will capture items in a comma separated list on either side of the word "and."  It gets complicated when an item can look like: `item (sub item 1, sub item 2) and other item, ...`. It gets even worse when that previous example is a sub item of something else.  The regex I have now is `/([^,]*(?:\(.*\))?[^,]*)( and )([^,]*(?:\(.*\))?[^,]*)/i` but it's not working right.

Comment: Try using http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: I am.  It's helped get me closer, but I'm still not there.

Comment: So in your example, you would expect to extract `sub item 1` and `sub item 2`? This sort of a recursive definition isn't particularly well suited for regex.

Comment: I want it to capture `item (sub item 1, sub item 2)` and `other item`

Comment: You should explode the string into an array based on the "," and regex through each piece to get the strings you want. -J

Comment: Why not just explode on `and`? https://eval.in/427703

Comment: Because I also have to do this with "or" and "and/or" and retaining the list order would be difficult if I did that because I don't know how everything will be nested.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a single regex. Extract parts at a time. First explode on the word `and`

That gives you x arrays (in your case 2)

Then in that array you have a single item which can contain 0+ sub items

`preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $item, $match);`

You can then process $match[1] (explode on the comma), remove the brackets from the string and you are left with just an item

Im not 100% sure what sort of data structure you are wanting to end with. But following the regex here + 2 explodes you should be able to process all

You will likely want to make use of `trim` too

Comment: I don't think that would work in my example.  If I'm understanding it right, that would match all the sub items and not the "item" outside the parentheses.  Also I need to do this for "or" and "and/or", so exploding multiple times would make it hard to maintain what order the items are in.

Comment: It would match both the item and the sub item and link together. And and or become hard to match you need to decide which a left / right associtavity

Answer (score 0):

You can match these substrings with the following regex:

```
(?<=^|,)
(?<before>[^,]*?
  (?:
    (\((?>[^()]+|(?2))*\))
    [^,]*
  )*
)
\s+and\s*
(?<after>[^,]*?
  (?:
    (\((?>[^()]+|(?4))*\))
    [^,]*
  )*
)
(?=,|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3jD1/1)

The `before` and `after` are the parts  The `(\((?>[^()]+|(?2))*\))` and `(\((?>[^()]+|(?4))*\))` subpatterns are subroutines that match nested parentheses.

[One-liner](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3jD1/2):

```
(?<=^|,)(?<before>[^,]*?(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?2))*\))[^,]*)*)\s+and\s*(?<after>[^,]*?(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?4))*\))[^,]*)*)(?=,|$)
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you.  That's really close.  An actual example of a string is `ENZYMES (WITHOUT ANIMAL ENZYMES and RENNET)`. Your regex will match `ENZYMES (WITHOUT ANIMAL ENZYMES` and not just `WITHOUT ANIMAL ENZYMES`.  Also, I think the `*` in `\s+and\s*` should be a `+`.